# can anyone explain me why I need this command?

Tags: docker

I have seen a few tutorials about docker but then I saw this on a web page

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node

WORKDIR /home/node

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

So why I need this and whats chown -R

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node
```

Comment: What happens if you remove it? The answer is usually self-evident: Likely permission problems. Remember, for most command-line questions: `man chown`

Comment: See also in dockerhub the documentation for the base node image at https://hub.docker.com/_/node. It contains a "How to use this image" section, that in turn has a "Best practices" section that explains why it is fiddling with the user: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#non-root-user

Comment: I might delete that line entirely (`WORKDIR` will create the directory), also remove the `COPY --chown` option, and move `USER` to the end of the file.  The `npm install` step will run as root and root will own all of the files, but they'll be world-readable, and you'll be protected from accidentally overwriting your application code or static assets.

Answer (score 3):

Your `mkdir` command creates a sub-folder within the `node` folder, and the `chown -R` command changes ownership of the folder to the user `node` recursively (the folder and all it's contents).

This is required because the `node` app uses the `node` user to create files and folders in the `/home/node` directory.  This is important from a cybersecurity perspective, especially if you don't want the app running as an `admin` or `root` account.

Comment: thank you! One little question about this, whats means -p behind the folder path ?

Comment: the man pages are your friend https://manpages.org/mkdir